# Concatenating using MID and LEFT in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm currently writing a macro that will allow me to open a file, insert 3 rows and concatenate various parts of the file to allow me to create a unique string that I can reference in a VLOOKUP. I'm trying to use the formula **CONCATENATE(Mid(E8, 7, 2), "/", Mid(E8, 5, 2), "/", Left(E8, 4))** and my code looks like:

```
Sub OpenDCSheet()

Dim OpenFileName As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim LastRow As Long

MasterSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Name

'Select and Open workbook
MsgBox ("Please select the data file")
OpenFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename
If OpenFileName = "False" Then Exit Sub
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(OpenFileName, UpdateLinks = 0)

DoubleClickSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Name

  Windows(DoubleClickSheet).Activate
'Inserting a Column at Column B
[B3].Resize(, 3).EntireColumn.Insert

Range("B8").Select
    ActiveCell.Formula = CONCATENATE(Mid(E8, 7, 2), "/", Mid(E8, 5, 2), "/", Left(E8, 4))
```

Can anyone troubleshoot why this doesn't work?

Thanks,

Aaron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plan to Vlookup the unique string.

I will recommend you using User Defined Function(UDF) to join.
Rather using concatenate.

Below are the differential between both of them:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Rw5r.gif)

Will dealing with date, concatenate will bring in another problem.

Below is the UDF I created:

```
Function joinCell(ByVal inputRange As Range) As String
Dim nCell As Range
Dim nText As String
    For Each nCell In inputRange.Cells
        nText = nText & Trim(CStr(nCell.Value))
    Next
    joinCell = nText
End Function
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks for your help both. The unq. string that I'm going to be creating will be looking up date, and campaign name so I was orignally planning to store it as text. Do you think this may be an issue? Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: @aaron2295 you're right, good idea to store as text. But when you get it from a cell, need to be .Value, Using .Text will become problem, when date using different formatting.

Comment: Hi Eric, I thought by using the TEXT function within my concatenated string I might get around this? Let me know if this won't work.

Comment: It can, only if you provide the format. and that's the problem to identify the format. You can have a try.

Answer (score 1):

You were very close.  Consider:

```
ActiveCell.Formula = "=CONCATENATE(Mid(E8, 7, 2), ""/"", Mid(E8, 5, 2), ""/"", Left(E8, 4))"
```

*This only addresses errors in this single line of code.  You may have other problems.*

Comment: Thanks Gary's student !!! worked perfectly.